# Python program to pull list data and calculate multiple equations

Tags: python, list, file

I had help earlier for the sentinel loop and it helped me get far, but I am stuck again after spending several hours messing around with this code. I am looking to do the following:

- only allow the user to enter the score between 0 and 100, or else the program will kick the user back with a message
- display the median value of the class scores

I'm really not too sure where to go from here:

```
def get_data():
    student = input("Please enter a student's last name (<Enter> to quit): ")
    if student:
        grade = input("Please enter the student's grade (<Enter> to quit): ")
        if grade.isdigit():
            return (student, eval(grade))            
    return (None, None)

def main():
    print("Please use this program for your students' test scores.\n")

    outfile = open("Data.txt", 'w')

    (student, grade) = get_data()
    while student:
        print(student, grade, file = outfile)
        (student, grade) = get_data()

    outfile.close()

    outfile = open("Data.txt", 'r')    

    numRow = 0.0
    total2 = 0.0
    score = []

    for line in outfile:
        col1, col2 = line[:-1].split(" ")
        col2 = eval(col2)
        print(col1, col2)
        total2 = col2 + total2
        numRow = numRow + 1
        score.append(col2)

    avg = total2/ numRow

    print(f"The average of the test scores is: {avg:.2f}")
    print("The largest test score is:",max(score))
    print("The lowest test score is:",min(score))

main()
```

Comment: Does "any score above 50 will be listed" mean you want a list of student names and scores for scores above 50?

Comment: @DarryIG just the scores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated your code to provide

- only allow the user to enter the score between 0 and 100, or else the program will kick the user back with a message
- any score above 50 will be listed
- display the median value of the class scores

**Code**

```
def get_data():
    student = input("Please enter a student's last name (<Enter> to quit): ")
    if student:
        while True:
          grade = input("Please enter the student's grade (<Enter> to quit): ")

          try:
            grade = float(grade)  # note used float since eval use
                                  # is discouraged except for special
                                  # circumstances
            if 0 <= grade <= 100:
              break
            print('Grade should be between 0 and 100')

          except:
            print('Grade should be numeric')

        return (student, grade)   # grade already converted
                                  # no need to convert again

    return (None, None)

def main():
    print("Please use this program for your students' test scores.\n")

    with open("Data.txt", 'w') as outfile:
      (student, grade) = get_data()

      while student:
          print(student, grade, file = outfile)
          (student, grade) = get_data()

    with open("Data.txt", 'r') as outfile:

      numRow = 0.0
      total2 = 0.0
      score = []

      for line in outfile:
          col1, col2 = line[:-1].split(" ")
          col2 = float(col2)
          if col2 >= 50:      # List scores above 50
           print(col1, col2)
          total2 = col2 + total2
          numRow = numRow + 1
          score.append(col2)

      avg = total2/ numRow

      # find the median, just sort the list and return the number in the 
      # middle position or (if the list has even number of elements), 
      # median is the average of the 2 elements in middle:
      score.sort()
      n = len(score)
      m = n - 1
      median =  (score[n//2] + score[m//2]) / 2.0


      print(f'The average of the test scores is: {avg:.2f}')
      print(f'The median test score is: {median}')
      print(f'The largest test score is: {max(score)}')
      print(f'The lowest test score is: {min(score)}')

main()
```